# Flutter: child.ref.remove and children.length not counting properly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Flutter and I have an app in which I want to remove and add books to my Firebase RealTime Database.

The problem is when I try to remove a book by clicking on an icon, the book is indeed removed from the Firebase, however, when I run some code further down, in which i need the quantity of books on the wishlist, it always counts 1 more than the real number.

Here's my code in which I remove the selected book:

```
// Which means the book was in the wishlist already, so we have to remove it
if (isBookWishb) {
  for (DataSnapshot element in userTable.children) {
    if (element.key == widget.userID) {
        if (element.child("BOOKS_WISH").exists) {
          for (int i = 0; i < element.child("BOOKS_WISH").children.length; i++) {
            if (element.child("BOOKS_WISH").child(i.toString()).value.toString() == widget.book.bookID) {
              element.child("BOOKS_WISH").child(i.toString()).ref.remove();
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        isBookWishb = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I retrieve the quantity of books a certain user has (on the same for loop, for example)

```
element.child("BOOKS_WISH").children.length
```

And here's my database [image: here's my database]

**When I remove "2131313", it still counts the quantity correctly, same thing when I add it back. The problem occurs when I try to remove "56" or "6". If I remove one of these, the quantity after I do it still shows up as 3, when it should be 2, so when I add the book to the database again, it goes to 4 instead of 3**

I've tried .set(null) instead, giving a few seconds to make sure I'm not overlapping the firebase process with my prints, but nothing seems to work.
Because of this small thing, my whole project is ruined, and I can't seem to fix it. Thanks in advance for your attention

Comment: How is `userTable` populated? I'd recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (again), as the more you can isolate the problem (hard-coding values, not depending on UI, etc), the more likely it is that we can help.

Comment: Right now, everything about the userTable was inserted manually in firebase. The books seem to be the only thing I did dynamically through code and UI. I'm almost 100% sure the UI works properly, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to add and remove the book in the last position i.e. "2131313" @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Firebase array!

Arrays are often difficult to use in NoSQL Databases (The Realtime Database in particular); you cannot insert or remove individual elements as the array is treated as one object, and the indexing will never change; e.g. value 2131313 is 'stuck' at index 2.

If you want to update an array, it has to be read, modified in code and re-written.

See this classic blog [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase).

A better option is to store each book with it's own firebase generated key. Then you can easily add/edit or remove.

So it would look like this

```
BOOKS_WISH
   -Y0kmos9j9h8fg: "56"
   -Y0joa90i90skl: "6"
   -Y0ziklklakldd: "2131313"
```

where `-Y0kmos9j9h8fg` etc are firebase generated keys

That structure also provides a lot more flexibility!

```
BOOKS_WISH
   -Y0kmos9j9h8fg:
       bookNum: "56"
       bookTitle: "Some title"
   -Y0joa90i90skl:
       bookNum: "6"
       bookTitle: "Another title"
   -Y0ziklklakldd:
       bookNum: "2131313"
       bookTitle: "Yet another title"
```

Now you can query, sort, etc on your book list. You could even add another node 'sort_index' to use for sorting

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It seems like that was indeed the problem :)